# not read the file. htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to help me please if it is in their hands.

And in advance thank you who have read my problem.

The problem is this:

In my local server (localhost) I did not read the file. htaccess, I checked my httpd.conf and rewrite module is active, since it is not the pad

So this:

```
Rewrite_module LoadModule modules / mod_rewrite.so
```

But still I do not read the apache server

I have also seen that the AllowOverride None deny nor do I read, I've tried putting # AllowOverride None but I do not read.

I have two files:

First file: index.php, this file I have two results

and second: ver.php

And when I click on index.php do I send it to:

```
ver.php? idmini = 1

http://pablodelriob.kodingen.com/mininoticias2/ver.php?idmini=1
```

And I can not run the url friendly. htaccess

To leave my doubt also increased all the files on a server on the Internet, the address is at:

http://pablodelriob.kodingen.com/mininoticias2

The contents of my file. htaccess is:

```
Mod_rewrite.c> <IfModule
# Options + FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^ view (.*) \. html $ ver.php? idmini = $ 1
</ IfModule>
```

Be possible to help me?

Thanks for reading

Comment: Explain what is not happening. Do you get an error screen? Can you check the error log files of your webserver?

Answer (score 4):

If you put garbage in your htaccess file, and you don't get a 500 error, AllowOverride is set to none in your base apache configuration.  It needs to be set to at least FileInfo to use rewrite in htaccess.

You mention adding "AllowOverride None", but this is exactly the opposite of what you want.